# WPF mvvm backgroundworker UI displaying different results

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, backgroundworker

So finally i managed to create a working BackgroundWorker.

I used the ReportProgress method to updated UI elements in this way:

```
 bw.ReportProgress(1, node);
 bw.ReportProgress(2, connection);
 bw.ReportProgress(3);
 bw.ReportProgress(4, system);
```

Where the connection is a model Object, this is my progress method:

```
 void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ProgressPercentage == 1)       //update nodes
        {
            this.Network.Nodes.Add((NodeViewModel)e.UserState);
        }
        if (e.ProgressPercentage == 2)       //update connections
        {
            this.Network.Connections.Add((ConnectionViewModel)e.UserState);
        }
        if (e.ProgressPercentage == 3)
        {
            this.Network.Connections.Clear();
            this.Network.Nodes.Clear();
        }
        if (e.ProgressPercentage == 4)
        {
            MainNet.Systems.Add((Common.Model.System)e.UserState);
        }
    }
```

I have multiple objects to update so I used the percentage as a filter.

I'm getting different results every time i run the code, as if some of the data is not rendered correctly in the UI

The correct form of UI:

[image: This is the correct form of UI]

Not correct:

[image: This is not correct]

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you call `ReportProgress()`?

Comment: Is it a race condition?

Comment: @GarryVass what is race conditions?

Slugart - It's in the main message on the top, this is all the `ReportProgress` call, i have other calls also, ill add them now

Comment: Your edit helped!  Can you show an example of 'not rendered correctly'?  Or describe it explicitly?  I'm still guessing it's a race.

Comment: Wow that's a surprise lol i thought it will be not helpful, give a second i'll add two print screens

Comment: @GarryVass i updated my question with the printscreens

Comment: Yup.  Can you please read this article and let me know if it helps?  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/race-conditions-in-threading-C-Sharp/

Comment: @GarryVass it looks like my problem, but i'm using the backgroundWorker, isn't that supposed to be safe? because it's updating on demand, or not?
How i can modify the example you gave me to the background worker? 
A `lock` might help?

Comment: Yes, the progress is marshalled to the UI thread and in that sense it is safe.  But marshalling does not always guarantee synchronization.  Different animals.  Exacerbated by your giving a logical value to the percentage :)

Comment: Update: i tried `lock` didn't work

Comment: You are so close on helping me to finish my Bs.c final project :) lol and i really need some help (my mind is not here anymore) what else could i try instead of the `lock` method?

Comment: It's a DESIGN problem.  Based upon what you wrote, it looks like a sequential queue of bg workers would be my approach.  Get the results from number 1 worker, then start number 2 worker, etc.  But I haven't seen the whole code, so it's a casual generic recommendation.

Comment: Ok so i narrow it down and figured out the problem, I need to "wait" for the `ReportProgress` to end right? how do i do that?

Comment: Read my last comment :)

Comment: Maybe you can write an example as an answer? i don't have time to loose on another debugging and i think i'm not fully understand

Comment: I think i realized what you are suggesting and i cann't do that because my main method supposed to be a complete one, is there any other why? to wait for the `ReportProgress` to end?

Comment: Solution given.  See if it's of any use...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to synchronize your worker(s) to avoid reentrancy or a race, there are several different ways.  You can try an approach like this...

```
    private static void ManageBackgroundWorkers()
    {
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker2 = new BackgroundWorker();
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker3 = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += (s, a) =>
        {
            /* do stuff*/
        };
        backgroundWorker2.DoWork += (s, a) =>
        {
            /* do some more stuff*/
        };
        backgroundWorker3.DoWork += (s, a) =>
        {
            /* do even more different stuff*/
        };
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) =>
        {
            //this.Network.Nodes.Add((NodeViewModel)e.UserState);
            backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
        };
        backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) =>
        {
            //this.Network.Connections.Add((ConnectionViewModel)e.UserState);
            backgroundWorker3.RunWorkerAsync()
        };
        backgroundWorker3.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) =>
        {
            // finish remaining tasks here
        };
        /* start the queue */
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Each worker signals a completion and its event handler simply starts the next worker in the series.  It is not a massive difference in what you have, but it repackages the steps that you were using the 'Percentage' property for.  Percentage is really a bad proxy for state anyway.  Refactoring your code should take about 5 minutes.

An alternative method is to instrument the callback with an ManualResetEvent that signals each time it is called.  And the ManualResetEven is waited upon in the worker after each call to the ReportProgress handler.  Messier, less modular, but indeed workable.

Comment: unfortunately this does not help my situation, i can't modify the main method so it will be broken to many parts, is there any other way?

Comment: If your Bachelor's degree requires you to do everything in your 'main method' (which isn't included in your problem statement), then consider changing to a different university.

Comment: NO no lol, don't worry about that (i have 124 classes and windows in my program..) but the function i'm talking about can not be broken

Comment: Answer amended.  That's all I can do on this question :)